# Why my stdout is empty in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am able to convert `pdf` file to `png` successfully. But I am not getting value of `stdout`.

```
exec('gm convert -monitor http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf[0] myFile.png', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.dir(stdout);
});
```

error is **null** and result `stdout`  is `''`;

Why I am getting empty `stdout`?

Comment: Anything on `stderr`?

Comment: i m getting Stderr

Comment: Try priniting `stderr` and `error`

Comment: error is null.. and stderr is Saving image: 612x792...  \r   67% [myFile.png] Saving image: 6

Comment: Then maybe the output you see when you execute it directly is actually stderr and the program isnt using stdout but stderr instead

Comment: Can you verify the `gm convert...` command is actually writing something to stdout on the command line? For example by running the command manually and redirecting its error output elsewhere, e.g. `gm convert... 2> /dev/null`, if it does not output anything then, the command puts its output on the stderr by default.